# Как создать объект с помощью рефлексии?

Tags: java, рефлексия

Существует несколько вариантов для создания объекта в Java. Слышал, что есть вариант с рефлексией. Как это можно реализовать?
А также в чем суть названия этого метода создания объекта?

Comment: Вас интересует количество вариантов, сами варианты, или подробности с вариантом рефлексии?

Comment: давайте сразу Unsafe

Comment: @LEQADA Именно подробности с рефлексией, да!
Или может существуют еще какие-нибудь варианты, кроме этих трех?

Comment: Можно клонировать существующий объект. Тогда создастся новый. Вы уже решите, что именно вам нужно и поменяем постановку вопроса.

Comment: @LEQADA Конкретно мне нужна рефлексия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Class.newInstance()`
2. `Constructor.newInstance()`
3. `Unsafe.allocateInstance()`
4. Десериализация объекта.

Comment: Вы так выделили десериализацию, как будто она реализована через какой-то четвёртый способ. Я джаву не знаю, но что-то мне кажется, что любая десериализация в конечном счёте пользуется стандартными методами. Кстати, объяснить разницу между вариантами не повредит, хотя бы в двух словах.

Answer (score 1):

Вся суть рефлексии в динамичности. В этом случае вы можете создавать тот объект, который нужен в зависимости от условий. Вы можете получить название класса из БД, в результате вычислений, из файла и т.д.

С помощью рефлексии объект создавать можно следующим образом:

Допустим, что у нас есть класс `Reflect`, объект которого мы будем создавать

```
public class Reflect {

    public Reflect () {
        System.out.println("Hello from reflect class constructor");
    }
}
```

Напишем класс `Main`, в котором будет создаваться объект класса `Reflect`

```
public class Main {

    public static void main (String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        Class c = Class.forName("Reflect");
        Object object = c.newInstance();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello from reflect class constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

наверное вы имеете ввиду class.newInstance();

Comment: Там вызывается оператор new, в этом методе.