# Java - Как вызвать функцию из класса по String

Tags: java, классы

Мне надо, чтобы по названию из String переменной можно было найти из пакета класс и вызвать из него нужный метод способом актуальным для `JDK 21`, а актуальные варианты под `JDK 21` я не нашел.
`Class.getDeclaredConstructor()` у меня не находит `IDE`:
[image: не находит]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как создать объект с помощью рефлексии?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477383/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: там все устарело после JDK 9

Comment: Что "устарело", метод [`Class::newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance())?  Так в документации указано, как его заменить с помощью вызова `clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()`

Comment: @NowhereMan у меня не находит

Comment: Естественно, что не находит, строка с названием класса должна передаваться в статический метод [`Class.forName`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)), затем у полученного **экземпляра 'Class'** можно вызвать метод `getDeclaredConstructor(java.lang.Class...)`, чтобы получить конструктор (если список параметров класса пустой, то вызв вернёт конструктор по умолчанию), и только после этого вызвать конструктор с необходимыми параметрами `Constructor::newInstance`

Comment: В показанном коде вы пытаетесь вызвать метод `getDeclaredConstructor` как **статический**, разумеется, компилятор не может его найти.

Comment: у меня уже все работает, я разобрался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример в онлайн-компиляторе [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/WDw) с Java 21:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class MyClass {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Current JVM version: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
        
        Class<String> clzz = (Class<String>) Class.forName("java.lang.String");
        
        Constructor<String> ctrStringChars = clzz.getDeclaredConstructor(char[].class);
        
        // создание объекта при помощи конструктора
        String reflected = ctrStringChars.newInstance(new char[]{'H', 'i'});
        System.out.println(reflected);
        
        // вызов метода для объекта
        Method repeat = clzz.getMethod("repeat", int.class);
        String repeated = ((Class<String>)repeat.getReturnType()).cast(repeat.invoke(reflected, 3));
        System.out.println(repeated);
        
        // вызов статического метода
        Method valueOf = clzz.getMethod("valueOf", int.class);
        String statResult = ((Class<String>)valueOf.getReturnType()).cast(valueOf.invoke(null, 123));
        System.out.println(statResult);
        
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Current JVM version: 21
Hi
HiHiHi
123
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]